# TSQL Order results by value of subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that is pulling out submissions from one table and then the count of votes from another table. I then want to order the records based on the total votes which is gathered from a sub query.

How can I order this table by totalVotes which is gathered in the subquery?

```
SELECT A.[submissionID],
       A.[entryID],
       E.[subEmpID],
       E.[nomineeEmpID],
       CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), E.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
       E.[situation],
       E.[task],
       E.[action],
       E.[result],
       E.[timestamp],
       E.[statusID],
       E.[approver],
       E.[approvalDate],
       B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
       B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
       B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
       C.[FirstName] + ' ' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
       C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
       D.[categoryName],
       (
            SELECT count(G.[empID]) as totalVotes FROM empowermentVotes as G WHERE entryID = A.[entryID]
            ORDER BY totalVotes ASC
            FOR    XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS
       ) 
FROM   empowermentEntries AS A
       INNER JOIN empowermentSubmissions as E
       ON A.[submissionID] = E.[submissionID]
       INNER JOIN
       empTable AS B
       ON E.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
       INNER JOIN
       empTable AS C
       ON E.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
       INNER JOIN
       empowermentCategories AS D
       ON E.[categoryID] = D.[catID]
WHERE  A.[sessionID] = @sessionID
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: Give the column an alias and order by the alias.

Comment: `Invalid column name 'totalVotes'` when trying to access the alias in the outer select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to order it before the FOR XML:

```
SELECT(
SELECT A.[submissionID],
       A.[entryID],
       E.[subEmpID],
       E.[nomineeEmpID],
       CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), E.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
       E.[situation],
       E.[task],
       E.[action],
       E.[result],
       E.[timestamp],
       E.[statusID],
       E.[approver],
       E.[approvalDate],
       B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
       B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
       B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
       C.[FirstName] + ' ' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
       C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
       D.[categoryName],
       (
            SELECT count(G.[empID]) as totalVotes FROM empowermentVotes as G WHERE entryID = A.[entryID]
            ORDER BY totalVotes ASC
            FOR    XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS
       ) votes
FROM   empowermentEntries AS A
       INNER JOIN empowermentSubmissions as E
       ON A.[submissionID] = E.[submissionID]
       INNER JOIN
       empTable AS B
       ON E.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
       INNER JOIN
       empTable AS C
       ON E.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
       INNER JOIN
       empowermentCategories AS D
       ON E.[categoryID] = D.[catID]
WHERE  A.[sessionID] = @sessionID
ORDER BY votes
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
)
```

please note the outer select and alias added

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it by ORDER BY  (19 in your case) or possibly by alias.  However SQL does not always let you do this.  It may throw an error about "Must have at least one non-external reference..." (something like that anyway).  If that is the case you may have to wrap the whole query in a CTE or subquery and the order the outer query.  One additional option is to order it in your middle tier.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Linoff said above in a comment, give the column an alias, and reference that in your ORDER BY.

Example:

```
SELECT A.SubmissionID,
 ...
 ...
(
    SELECT count(G.[empID]) as totalVotes FROM empowermentVotes as G WHERE entryID = A.[entryID]
     ORDER BY totalVotes ASC
           FOR    XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS
 ) AS TotalVotes
FROM empowermentEntries AS A
...
...
WHERE blah blah blah
ORDER BY TotalVotes
```

Comment: as I said on his response, `Invalid column name 'totalVotes'` when trying to order by an alias that is not in the outer select

Comment: the error is `The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.
`

Comment: Is FOR XML really needed there, since the outer query uses FOR XML already?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT A.[submissionID],
       A.[entryID],
       E.[subEmpID],
       E.[nomineeEmpID],
       CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), E.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
       E.[situation],
       E.[task],
       E.[action],
       E.[result],
       E.[timestamp],
       E.[statusID],
       E.[approver],
       E.[approvalDate],
       B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
       B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
       B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
       C.[FirstName] + ' ' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
       C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
       D.[categoryName],
       (
            SELECT count(G.[empID]) as totalVotes FROM empowermentVotes as G WHERE entryID = A.[entryID]
            ORDER BY totalVotes ASC
            FOR    XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS
       ) As TotalVotes
FROM   empowermentEntries AS A
       INNER JOIN empowermentSubmissions as E
       ON A.[submissionID] = E.[submissionID]
       INNER JOIN
       empTable AS B
       ON E.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
       INNER JOIN
       empTable AS C
       ON E.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
       INNER JOIN
       empowermentCategories AS D
       ON E.[categoryID] = D.[catID]
WHERE  A.[sessionID] = @sessionID
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.TotalVotes
```